# wrong SOAP request getting created

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

This is what my code is creating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://example.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ws:isUserExists>
            <userId>10</userId>
        </ws:isUserExists>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In my **soapenv:Envelope**  || **xmlns:soapenv** is coming twice

```
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
```

Now this is what I need:
here `xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` is not present in the SOAP request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ " xmlns:ws="http://example.com"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <ws:isUserExists> 
            <userId>10</userId> 
        </ws:isUserExists> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The java code which I am using to create the request is:

```
public static SOAPMessage createIsUserExistsSOAPRequest(User user) throws SOAPException
    {
        MessageFactory messageFactory =MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("soapenv");
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.setPrefix("soapenv");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ws","http://example.com");

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        soapBody.setPrefix("soapenv");
        SOAPElement ensureUserExistsElem = soapBody.addChildElement("isUserExists", "ws");
        SOAPElement userIdElem = ensureUserExistsElem.addChildElement("userId");
        userIdElem.addTextNode(user.userId);
        String authorization = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(("someid@gmail.com").getBytes());
        MimeHeaders hd = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        return soapMessage;
    }
```

Please help : what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my soapenv:Envelope || xmlns:soapenv is coming twice

It does not appear twice. You're defining 2 prefixes that are bound to the same namespace.

---

> xmlns:**soapenv**="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>
> xmlns:**SOAP-ENV**="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

---

> Please help : what I am doing wrong?

Nothing. It does not matter if the namespace prefix is `soapenv` or `SOAP-ENV` or `polar-bear-ninjas`. As long as the prefix is bound to a namespace you are fully qualifying that XML element. Both XMLs are valid and it does not matter which prefix is used.

Comment: True, is much like defining a variable. Then you can either use it or not. Is redundant but the XML is valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here I have another doubt : I want ti remove the  **standalone="no"**  from **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>**, or should I Post a different question for this doubt ?

Comment: That is quite odd. Are you referring to a DTD somewhere in the document or in the code that is supposed to process this XML ? That is where standalone becomes useful. Create another question and fill in the details there, since we'd need to ask you a couple of questions to get to the answer.